# Odd characters in wysiwyg

Tags: character, wysiwyg, redactor

I am using Redactor.

When pasting in text whether its from Word or Textedit I am getting really odd characters after saving.

For example an apostrophe is being changed to `â€™` and any time I open that page and re save it adds even more characters like this `‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â`

The page uses `utf-8` charset

Any help would be great. Thank you

Comment: Pasting from word can mess up formatting in the WYSIWYG editor, but you can bypass it by pasting into the HTML view or as they did it in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265321/redactor-js-pasteplaintext-but-need-button-to-paste-html-instead